# Button function returning user operating system and browser version?

Tags: button, browser, operating-system, version, system

I run a site that redirects to a 'We're Sorry' page for users of IE 7 or less until I create a IE downgraded version of the website.

What I really want is a button on the page that when pressed, sends an email to me with the users operating system and browser version.

Any ideas how I could make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

User agent sniffing is bad! Try to detect the necessary features or inhibiting defects instead.

If you really need to do it,

- evaluate the user agent string of the HTTP request header on the server side, or
- evaluate `window.navigator` on the client side and tell the server about it.

Since both methods need the cooperation of the server, but only the second needs the one of client, I would go for the first, because it only requires changes in one place.